# Plugin development: How do you support date formatting in parse_variables?

Tags: templates, add-on-development, plugin, date-format

I'm trying to support date formatting of a tag's output, per the Plugin Development & Template Class documentation. I have this code on the backend, with some redundancy on the timestamp value to ensure that, yes, this is a timestamp!

```
$append = array(
        'timestamp' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['timestamp'])),
        'username' => $row['username'],
        'screen_name' => $row['screen_name'],
        'email' => $row['email']
    );
$output .= $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $append);
```

If I use the tag `{timestamp}` in my template, I get the timestamp value: 1363956000.

If I use `{timestamp format="%l, %F %j, %Y - %g:%i %A"}` in my template, the output is: `{timestamp format="%l, %F %j, %Y - %g:%i %A"}`.

According to the docs, this should just work, though – [Template Class/Date Variables](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#date-variables).

How do you support formatting of timestamp values in a plugin's output?

Comment: I've just tried adding a `gmmktime()` var to one of my fieldtype's response arrays and it does support formatting automatically. The only thing that strikes me is that you seem to be passing a single row to `parse_variables` rather than an array of them. I'm surprised that's working at all, but maybe that's a factor? Is your sample code copied verbatim?

Comment: Second part did the trick. If you want to switch your comment to an answer, I'll give you the credit. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, glad to hear that worked. I've fleshed out my comment a bit and reposted it as an answer.

Comment: And you answered how I get `total_results` in another tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you're passing a single row to `parse_variables` (which normally expects an array of rows). If you switch to [parse_variables_row](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#parsing-a-single-result-row) that should help:

> You may also parse the result rows yourself, which could be useful if for some reason you need to modify the tagdata for each row based on certain criteria. You can still benefit from the simplified variable parsing by using parse_variables_row(), though you will no longer automatically have {count}, {total_results}, or {switch=} variables. To include these variables when parsing your own result rows, you will need to add them yourself.

If you'd prefer to retain `count`, `total_results` etc then you can also easily tweak your existing code by wrapping `$append` in its own array:

```
$output .= $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, array($append));
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @Dom Stubbs' recommendation I used gmmktime(), it said it was type:int:

```
'timestamp' => gmmktime(date('H',$row['timestamp']),
    date('i',$row['timestamp']),
    date('s',$row['timestamp']),
    date('m',$row['timestamp']),
    date('d',$row['timestamp']),
    date('Y',$row['timestamp'])
    ),
        'username' => $row['username'],
        'screen_name' => $row['screen_name'],
        'email' => $row['email']
    );
var_dump($append);
```

Further following Dom's recommendation, switching to `$this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row` instead of `$this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables` is returning the correct value.

I was then able to switch back to:

```
$append = array(
        'timestamp' => $row['timestamp'],
        'username' => $row['username'],
        'screen_name' => $row['screen_name'],
        'email' => $row['email']
    );
$output .= $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $append);
```

Thanks, Dom!